# Unable to fetch data from existing document within subcollection (Swift & Firestore)

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

Messaging Structure:

**messages > currentUserID (document) > partnerID (collection) > message (document)**

I can get as far as retrieving the partner ID but I can't retrieve the individual messages (documents) within the collection. Heres the functions Im using:

```
func observeUserMessages(){
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    let dbRef = db.collection("messages").document(uid).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let snapshot = querySnapshot?.documentID else { return }
        print("This is the partner ID: \(snapshot)")
        self.fetchMessageWithPartnerID(partnerID: snapshot)
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

fileprivate func fetchMessageWithPartnerID(partnerID: String) {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    Firestore.firestore().collection("messages").document(uid).collection(partnerID).getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
        print("This is the snapchat count:\(snapshot?.count)")
    }
}
```

Results:

[image]

As you can see, it should show the two messages but its not returning anything.

Comment: When it's possible to copy text directly into your question (for error messages and such), please do so instead of showing a screenshot, as it's much easier to read and search.

Comment: You introduced a memory leak inside the closure. And also, do NOT use self. when it is not needed.

Comment: What do you mean by memory leak? mind explaining how? @J.Doe

Comment: Self.fetchmessage... is holding a strong reference to the current object. Hmm, in this situation maybe not, because dbRef will I think deinitialize instantly because you are not holding a ref to it

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a difference between `.collection()` and `.document()`. Try

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("messages").collection(uid).collection(partnerID).getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
    print("This is the snapchat count:\(snapshot?.count)")
}
```

Comment: collections hold documents. therefore if you have a collection, it can only contain documents but a document can contain a subcollection so your method won't work, but thank you so much for offering advice